# ionic 6 capacitor IOS app showing only white screen on app start

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I am trying to build a blank iOS project using ionic v6 capacitor 3. However when I run the app, it shows me only a blank white screen on IOS. When I try to debug in Xcode, the output is given as
'  KeyboardPlugin: resize mode - native
⚡️  Loading app at capacitor://localhost...
⚡️  WebView loaded'

I tried to debug on safari as well but the console is also empty.
There is no issue on the android version. My capacitor.config.ts file also has webDIR as 'www'. Please help on this one.

Comment: Having exactly the same problem, but I do not encounter this error when running on physical device. It seems to happen only with simulators. Have you tried to run on a real device ?

Comment: Yes it working now. The issue was the node version. I installed a new node version using nvm and it working fine now.

Comment: I am having the same issue. on the first time it shows white screen and if I run it again it works fine. I have ionic --version 6.18.1 and node --version v16.14.0 any help will be great!!!

Comment: Ionic:
   Ionic CLI                     : 6.18.1 
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.0.8
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 13.0.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 13.0.4
   @angular/cli                  : 13.0.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 5.0.3
Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 3.4.1
   @capacitor/android : not installed
   @capacitor/core    : 3.4.1
   @capacitor/ios     : 3.4.1

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.4
   native-run  : 1.5.0

System:

   NodeJS : v16.14.2 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 8.5.0
   OS     : macOS Big Sur